# How to call Base class method through base class pointer pointing to derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void foo()
    {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
  public:
    virtual void foo()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Base *pBase = NULL;
    Base objBase;
    Derived objDerived;

    pBase = &objDerived;
    pBase->foo();

    /*Here Derived class foo will be called, but i want this to call 
    a base class foo. Is there any way for this to happen? i.e. through 
    casting or something? */
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
pBase->Base::foo()
```

Answer (score 13):

Both responses above are correct...But be careful, if you need to do that, maybe you have a big problem about the conception or the design...

Comment: You are right: essentially this implies you need two methods.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through scope resolution operator `::`

Something like this:

```
pBase->Base::foo()
```