# Call virtual method from base class on object of derived type

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }
};

Derived d; // call Base::foo on this object
```

Tried casting and function pointers but I couldn't do it. Is it possible to defeat virtual mechanism (only wondering if it's possible)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Base class method through base class pointer pointing to derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136249/how-to-call-base-class-method-through-base-class-pointer-pointing-to-derived-cla)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To explicitly call the function `foo()` defined in `Base`, use:

```
d.Base::foo();
```

Comment: +1 for you too Daniel - strange how you're answer didn't show up at first for me.

Comment: @ChrisBD: After posting it, I suddenly realized that I couldn't remember ever having used this construct directly (only inside the definition of the function in the derived class). Hence, I decided to delete it for a while, until I was sure that it worked.

Answer (score 6):

```
d.Base::foo();
```

Note that `d.foo()` would call `Derived::foo` regardless of whether `foo` was virtual or not.

Comment: Er... Actually a fully-qualified name defeats *virtual dispath* specifically. You seem to be assuming that `d.foo()` call is not virtual. The language says nothing like that. `d.foo()` call is *virtual* from the language point of view, i.e. it is resolved in accordance with the dynamic type of `d`. If your compiler dispatches it statically, it is nothing else than an optimization done by your compiler (because the dynamic type is known at compile time). From the language point of view, the only way to defeat virtual dispatch is to use a fully-qualified name.

Comment: Well it defeats both. But `b->Base::foo` *only* defeats virtual dispatch.