# C++ How call the same method firstly from base class, then from derived?

Tags: c++

This code can help to understand, what I want:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        print("Base\n");
        Derived::foo(); // smth like that.
    }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        print("Derived\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  bar.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas ?

P.S. very bad idea is pass to foo pointer of derived.

Comment: A base class should typically be oblivious to (unaware of) its derived classes. Perhaps you should reconsider your system design, as your current implementation indicates that there might be a problem to begin with.

Comment: Consider doing things [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2787772/752261) way.

Comment: Niall, David Frye.... just...

Comment: You need the base class object to hold some short of a handle to it's derived object.

Comment: 40two, wou. may be, GetDerivedPtr() as virtual method ? and in function do this: GetDerivedPtr()->foo();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need the base class to hold some short of a handle of it's derived class like the example below:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
  T *handle;
protected:
  Base(T *_handle) : handle(_handle) {}
public:
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    handle->foo();
  }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
  Derived() : Base(this) { }
  void foo() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e446381d3069ff56)

Comment: If this is really what OP wants, nice job interpreting the poorly-communicated question.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you gave us a bunch of code sort of accomplishing what you wanted done, and then asked "any ideas?". You have to understand that this can be sort of difficult to work with, and getting upset when people propose alternatives doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787772/752261):

```
class Derived:public Base
{
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            Base::foo();
            print("Derived\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
    Derived bar;
    bar.foo();
}
```

seems to be what you want.

Comment: Whoa, settle down buddy. Why not this?

Comment: Check out [40two's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25067367/752261). It may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an abstract method in Base which sub-classes have to override, but you call it although it is abstract. This called Template Method:

```
class Base
{
public:
void foo() {
    print("Base\n");
    _foo();
}

private:
virtual void _foo() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
virtual void _foo() {
    print("Derived\n");
};
};
```

Another alternative would be to make Base a template and pass the Derived type:

```
template<class D>
class Base
{
public:
void foo() {
    print("Base\n");
    D::foo();
}
};

class Derived: public Base<Derived>
{
public:
void foo() {
    print("Derived\n");
};
};
```

I would usually go with the first approach as it is easier to grasp and also works with more than one level of inheritance.

Comment: In first method renaming of functions... not good for me. second seems good, but also it seems rickety.

Comment: Anyway, second method is really good solution. thanks for help.

Comment: @Aleksey What do you mean by renaming the function? THe public interface is foo(), and no client will ever see the internal virtual funciton. It is a well established pattern (Template Method, Non-virtual Interface) and clearly separates public client interface and implementation interface.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        Base::foo();
        printf("Derived\n");
    }
};
```

then

```
int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  bar.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

**OR**

```
int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  bar.Base::foo();
  bar.Derived::foo();   

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing static polymorphism, which is solved by [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename DERIVED>
class Base
{
  public:
    DERIVED & derived() { return *static_cast<DERIVED *>(this); }

    void foo()
    {
        print("Base\n");
        derived().foo();
    }
};

class Derived:public Base<Derived>
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        print("Derived\n");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a virtual function.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() const
    {
        Base::foo();
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};
void main()
{

    Derived d; // call Base::foo on this object
    d.foo();
    system("pause");
}
```