# How can a subclass call a method of the superclass with the same method name of the subclass?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    void sing();
};

class Child : public Person {
public:
    void sing();
};

Person::sing() {
    cout << "Raindrops keep falling on my head..." << endl;
}

Child::sing() {
    cout << "London bridge is falling down..." << endl;
}

int main() {
    Child suzie;
    suzie.sing(); // I want to know how I can call the Person's method of sing here!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Base class method through base class pointer pointing to derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136249/), [Call virtual method from base class on object of derived type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787756/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
suzie.Person::sing();
```

Comment: or `Person& sue = suzie; sue.sing();`.

Comment: or `static_cast<Person&>(suzie).sing();` or any variation thereof, yes.

Comment: I wrote that and then removed it.  I try to NEVER use a cast where an implicit conversion will work.

Answer (score 2):

The child can use Person::sign().

See http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/equivalent-of-keyword-base-in-c/ for a good explanation.