# overriding push_back c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, overriding, overloading

I have a class called `Path` that extends `std::vector<Square *>`, where `Square` is also a class that I have created.  The `Path` will serve as guide for an Entity traversing a 2D environment.  I have need of getting the longest path & shortest path acheivable, and therefore I am looking to find the number of squares between two `Squares` in a `Path`.  To do this, I feel that it would be beneficial to overload, `std::vector<Square *>::push_back(const  value_type &__x)`, although I am not sure what the syntax for that would be.  I am currently trying this:

```
class Path : public std::vector<Square *>
{   //... functional stuff, not relevant. 
    int length;
public:
    push_back(const value_type &__x)
    {   Square *last_square = this->at(this->size() - 1);

        // how do I call super class push_back?
        // however that works, I push back &__x square here.

        Square *most_recent = (Square *)&__x;
        int delta_x = compare_distance(last_square, most_recent);
        length += delta_x;
    };
    int path_length() { return length; };
};
```

Of course, I suppose I could just write a method inwhich I call push_back for the super class, but I feel like it is more concise to override the function, plus it is good practice for me to learn how to properly override stl functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287186/how-can-a-subclass-call-a-method-of-the-superclass-with-the-same-method-name-of

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooo, you're inheriting from a std::vector.  Kill it with fire!!1

Comment: Identifiers with double underscores are reserved. You should not use them. The standard library uses them because they are reserved for the standard library.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I guess I never imagined it could be bad practice to inherit from the STL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> plus it is good practice for me to learn how to properly override stl functions.

Actually, it's not.

STL containers are not meant to be inherited (no `virtual` method), therefore good practice is to use composition and provide a *meaningful interface* to your class that use the STL container methods to accomplish its goal.

Comment: Haha well its good for me to learn that it's not good practice.  Thanks Matthieu

Answer (score 4):

You can override *virtual* functions defined in a base class to get *dynamic polymorphism* - type-dependent behaviour determined at run time.

However, the STL containers use templates and non-virtual functions to give *static polymorphism* - type-dependent behaviour determined at compile time. There are no virtual functions to override, and so there's little point inheriting from them.

In particular, your class *hides* the base-class function; anyone calling `push_back` via a pointer/reference to `std::vector` rather than `Path` would not call your version, which may well lead to confusing bugs. A better approach would be compisition:

```
class Path {                        // no inheritance
    std::vector<Square *> squares;  // composition instead
public:
    void push_back(Square * x)      // Don't use __ in identifiers
    {
        squares.push_back(x);
        // do other stuff
    }
};
```

And to answer the question in the code comments, if you really do want to use inheritance for some weird reason, you can call the base-class version by qualifying the member name with the base class name:

```
std::vector<Square*>::push_back(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact you're using a `std::vector` is just an implementation detail. It could just as well be a `std::list`, or even a `std::set`.

This should give you the clue that you shouldn't commit yourself too strongly to the type.

Aggregate rather than inherit. You inherit to be re-used, which I don't think is what you need.

Additionally, the correct way to use the standard containers is to not inherit from them. They have no virtual destructor, and no virtual functions to override.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the others, in this case you would use composition or private inheritance (implemented-in-terms-of).

As a rule of thumb, ask the question and decide what to use based on which is truer:

- Path is implemented-in-terms-of std::vector

or

- Path is a std::vector

If "Path is a std::vector" is more accurate (so Path can not be std::list, or  std::deque, or MyFunnyContainer), derive from std::vector.
If "Path is implemented-in-terms-of std::vector" is more accurate, use composition or private inheritance.