# Using C++, how to call a base class method from a derived class method and apply this to an object passed as an argument?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I can't figure out how to call a base class method from a derived class method but concurrently applying this method call at an object passed as argument.

What I mean is this:

```
class Animal
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten) = 0;
 };

class Carnivores: public Animal
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten) { /*implementation here*/}

};

class Wolf : public Carnivores
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten)
    { /*call eat method(of Base class) of Base to_be_eaten here*/ }
 }
```

I thought of something like this

```
 dynamic_cast<Carnivores&>(to_be_eaten).eat(*this) //and got a segmentation fault
```

Is there any way for this to be done?

Thank you!

**New edit::
Updated the code**

Comment: What is the derivation of `Animal`? Is it related in any way to `Base`?

Comment: If you want it to call the base method and not do anything else, you could just skip the definition in the derived class.

Comment: @nikhil: Into the derived eat, there are some conditions that need to be met, in order for the eat of the Base class to be called.

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry, just changed it, Animal is the Base. The derived eat will call eat of Base class if some conditions are met (in example if the Animal is hungry).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357307/), [How to call Base class method through base class pointer pointing to derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136249/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
class Derived : public Base  {
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten) { 
        Base::eat(to_be_eaten);
        // do anything you want with to_be_eaten here.
    }
};
```

**EDIT**: This works for me:

```
class Animal
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten) = 0;
 };

class Carnivores: public Animal
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten) { /*implementation here*/}

};

class Wolf : public Carnivores
{ 
    virtual void eat(Animal& to_be_eaten)
    { 
        Carnivores *c = dynamic_cast<Carnivores*>(&to_be_eaten);
        if(c) 
            c->Carnivores::eat(*this);
    }
 }
```

Note that i had to make `Base::eat` public in order to call it from `Derived`.

Comment: I want to call the eat method of the to_be_eaten object. Not the "*this" object.

Comment: Just changed the "Animal" to "Base", sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Chris Done, check that new solution.

Comment: @Chris Could you explain better what you're trying to do? As far as i understand it, `to_be_eaten.Base::eat(*this)` will fix your code. But i assume that you have tested it and it's not what you want. Can you give us a better description?

Comment: We have this inheritance: Animal(ABC) > Carnivores(ABC) > Wolf(Derived). I have implemented a method called eat in Carnivores class that will eat the to_be_eaten animal. Also, I have implemented a method of Wolf, eat, that will eat the animal (if the wolf can eat it, depending on its speed and several other conditions). There might be a chance that the wolf tries to eat another animal that is bigger that it, so the other animal will it the wolf. This is what I am trying to do. Call eat method of Carnivores, for the "victim" (in the case that the victim is becoming a hunter).

Comment: Then my solution should work; what i did was to call `Animal::eat` on to_be_eaten, that means, the body of `Animal::eat`, making the *this instance == to_be_eaten. Have you tried it? How is it not working?

Comment: We want to call Carnivores::eat on to_be_eaten (which is of type Animal). A casting might be needed to change the type of to_be_eaten, from Animal, to Carnivores

Comment: Have you tried my solution!?!?!? A cast will do nothing, it will always call the derived class' override. `to_be_eaten.Carnivores::eat(*this)` Try that and tell me if it works, i've answered this 7 hours ago and you haven't told me if it has worked or not.

Comment: Sorry fontanini, I tried it and got this: "error: ‘Carnivores’ is not a base of ‘Animal’"...We are passing as an argument a reference to Animal.

Comment: I editted my answer, you do require a dynamic_cast. However, the fact that you have to dynamic cast and explicitly call Carivores::eat, implies you have a bad design in your code. I would first check if there's a better design you can use.

Comment: Well, this was the design that we were asked to implement. What do you think would be a better one? other use of functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9260/discussion-between-fontanini-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is not to use a virtual call on the parameter object (to_be_eaten). I think only an object can do that for himself. I don't think there's a way for other objects to do it for him.

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual eat(Base& to_be_eaten);
protected:
  virtual callEatNonVirtual(Base& other) = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
  virtual eat(Base& to_be_eaten)
  {
    to_be_eaten.callEatNonVirtual(*this);     
  }
protected:
  virtual callEatNonVirtual(Base& other)
  {
    Base::eat(other);
  } 
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
  virtual eat(Base& to_be_eaten)
  {
    to_be_eaten.callEatNonVirtual(*this);     
  }
protected:
  virtual callEatNonVirtual(Base& other)
  {
    Base::eat(other);
  } 
};
```

Comment: You've added lots of unnecessary code. `to_be_eaten.Base::eat(*this)`
 is enough to call `Base::eat`.